# Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev). occurred

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Xamarin.Android app that I'm trying to connect to firestore.

I'm creating a Firestore instance

```
FirebaseFirestore GetInst()
{
   var baseOptions = Firebase.FirebaseOptions.FromResource(context);
   var options = new Firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder(baseOptions).SetProjectId(baseOptions.StorageBucket.Split('.')[0]).Build();
   var app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(context, options, AppName);

   return FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);
}
```

Now, when trying to create a DocumentReference in my MainActivity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

   //body

   docRef = GetInst().Document("sampleData/samples"); 
}
```

The above exception is thrown on `GetInst().Document()`.

I can't find anything specific to Xamarin & firestore, and I can't debug it because it's external java code...

Logcat

```
AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejs.run(Unknown Source:21)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;
    at io.grpc.zzbm.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
    at io.grpc.zzbm.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.grpc.zzbi.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
    at io.grpc.zzbi.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.grpc.zzbm.zza(Unknown Source:3)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source:42)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(Unknown Source:20)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.zzp.zzty(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.zztt(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.grpc.zzbc.forTarget(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeid.<init>(Unknown Source:22)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeca.zza(Unknown Source:74)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecc.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejp$zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gogreenordietryin.mytem-cIxZrIRJzpVFvHHZ8Ok9SQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gogreenordietryin.mytem-cIxZrIRJzpVFvHHZ8Ok9SQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.gogreenordietryin.mytem-cIxZrIRJzpVFvHHZ8Ok9SQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: What is reported in `logcat`?

Comment: I have updated the original post to include the reports from logcat. Can you find something in there ?

Comment: `...java.lang.ClassNotFoundException...` Do you have Proguard|R8 enabled in that build configuration?

Comment: No, I don't have proguard enabled. AFAIK that also means I don't have R8 enabled. At least I couldn't find anything that would enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I find one thread that having same issue.

https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/pull/130

Maybe you can try to add **Xamarin.Google.Guava** in your project, and try it again.

Comment: Damn! Thanks alot! That actually fixed it.